# How can I solve $((6 \times 5280) - 17t)^2 + 5000^2 = (5t)^2$ algebraically rather than guess and check?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A puddle forms at an intersection with a radius at a rate of $5t$ feet where $t$ is the time in seconds. A jogger is located $6$ miles east and $5000$ feet north of the intersection, and is jogging west at a rate of $17t$ feet.
>
> When will the jogger's feet get wet (assuming the jogger starts jogging at the same time the puddle starts forming)?

I got a formula like this:

$$((6 \times 5280) - 17t)^2 + 5000^2 = (5t)^2$$

I cant figure out how to solve this equation for $t$. Is there another way to solve it? Or am I missing something? I'd rather not guess and check.

I've tried completing the square but it only seems to make the equation more complicated.

Comment: About the units : "6 miles east and 5000 north"? What are the units in the second quantity?

Comment: The equation you wrote down is just quadratic. Use the quadratic formula.

Comment: Cleat all parentheses (simplify) and collect all terms on one side. Then you will have a quadratic equation to solve for $t$.

Comment: Are you able to solve a quadratic equation ?

Comment: @MattiP. By default, miles, of course. Must be Forrest Gump ... ;) I just wonder how the jogger manges to accelerate that much -- after one minute they run at more than 100 ft/s, which seems to be something like 30 m/s in standard units

Comment: The units are 6 miles east and 5000 feet north, sorry forgot to include the feet. Thank you guys so much for recommending the quadratic formula! I dont have teacher and am just doing this from a book. I got pythagorean formula tunnel vision

Comment: You must have the question wrong $-$ $5t$ and $17t$ must be $5$ and $17$ for your equation to make sense.

Comment: I think I have the question right. I solved using the quadratic formula and it came out to 25.4 minutes if my memory serves rightly. The answer key said that answer was correct.

Comment: Then the question itself is wrong. It gives the jogger a constant acceleration, which is ridiculous, as @HagenvonEitzen points out (assuming that "$17t$ feet" means "$17t$ feet per second"). Is it in English?

Comment: There is no acceleration. It's at a rate of 17 feet per second.

Comment: Then why did you write "$17t$ feet" when you meant "$17$ feet per second"? Please make an effort to understand our concerns.

Comment: 17t feet is 17 feet per second, as I said t represents the time in seconds. This is how it's written in the book, which is published by the university of Washington. Your concerns are just misinterpretations.

Comment: No Matthew, they are not misinterpretations. If you have really transcribed the book faithfully, then the book is wrong, whatever university it comes from. $17t$ feet does not mean $17$ feet per second. (By the way, it helps if you include themagic word @TonyK when you reply to my comments. That way, I get notified.)

Comment: @TonyK That seems like a misinterpretation. What would 17t feet represent if not 17 feet per second (where t represents the time in seconds)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up a Cartesian coordinate system with origin at the center of the puddle, x-axis east-west, and y-axis north-south, units in feet.  The boundary of the "puddle" has equation $x^2+ y^2= 25t^2$.  The jogger, jogging west 5000 feet north of the puddle is running along the line y= 5000.  Initially, at t= 0, the jogger is 6 miles= 6(5280)= 31680 feet to the east so the joggers initial position in this coordinate system is (31680, 5000).  The jogger is jogging westward at 17t feet per second so the joggers postion after t seconds is (31680- 17t, 5000).

When, if ever, does x= 31680- 17t and y= 5000 satisfy $x^2+ y^2= 25t^2$?  That, of course, gives a quadratic equation in t so may have 0, 1, or two roots.  If there are no roots the jogger never touchs the water.  If one, the jogger just skirts the water.  If two, the smaller t gives the time when the "jogger's feet first get wet".

Comment: What do you mean by roots?